# C# When creating a button that does File.CreateText method, how can I prompt a request for a user to enter File Name and write a text line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm having problem to completely figure out File.CreatTextM Method.
What i'm trying to do is make a button that would prompt user to imput a text file name, prompt again to enter name, and finally create the text file in predestined location.

As far as i know in "Sring path =" you must predetermine name in the code, is there a command that opens a new window (or something) for user to input, so that i could store it to a variable and use in "Sring path ="

Or is there another approach for this?

Comment: but isn't there a way to promtp an additional window for input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use savefile dialog.
this code is from msdn

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
  // Displays a SaveFileDialog so the user can save the Image
  // assigned to Button2.
  SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
  saveFileDialog1.Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif        Image|*.gif";
   saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Image File";
  saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

   // If the file name is not an empty string open it for saving.
  if(saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
  {
   // Saves the Image via a FileStream created by the OpenFile method.
   System.IO.FileStream fs = 
     (System.IO.FileStream)saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
  // Saves the Image in the appropriate ImageFormat based upon the
  // File type selected in the dialog box.
  // NOTE that the FilterIndex property is one-based.
  switch(saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)
  {
     case 1 : 
     this.button2.Image.Save(fs, 
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
     break;

     case 2 : 
     this.button2.Image.Save(fs, 
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
     break;

     case 3 : 
     this.button2.Image.Save(fs, 
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
     break;
    }

    fs.Close();
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are using windows form, then you can use [saveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or for wpf win32 [saveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then you can get file name from this object. Use that filename to save your text.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no `InputBox` in `C#`, other than if you are creating a custom one. Best solution is to place some `textbox` control in your form for same purpose. Then you can get their values in `Button Click` event and perform the logic.

Comment: Could you give an example how the texbox is linked with File.CreateText method?

Answer (score 1):

You could create another Form with the necessary buttons and textboxes then show the form to the user, as referenced here : [Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16463738/4991153)