# How to customize tooltip UI in .Net framework 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip, .net-1.1

I am working in .Net framework 1.1 winforms. I need to customize the tooltip UI like change the backcolor and forecolor and adding the custom images on specific location. I can't override tooltip, Because of its sealed class . Even i can't change Backcolor and forecolor.

Is there any other way to customize tooltip?

Comment: .net 1.1? Really?

Comment: Yeah! i need it in .Net 1.1

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464085/WinForms-RichTextBox-ToolTip-like-Visual-Studios

Comment: Just out of sheer morbid curiosity, why .net 1.1 ?

Comment: @danish that samples also made above .net 2.0 version . Above 2.0 we can override the tooltip . but i need it in .Net 1.1.

Comment: @TheGeneral my requirement is .net 1.1 . i can't updagrade my project to higher versions.i had limitations on framework level.

Comment: Basically you need to upgrade the framework. I cannot think of a justification as to why not. There is no additional cost involved (basically money is the all it boils down to from what I have seen).

Comment: Maybe you could try to substitute tooltip with popup window like described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463599/popup-window-in-winform-c-sharp. Handle MouseOver and MouseLeave events on a target control and than show the popup on some timer event tick.

Comment: I don't know a single system the only supports .net 1.1... unless you are working with something like a windows server 2003 or even older